# How can we find all solutions to differential equations?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

I am wondering how is it possible to find non-differentiable functions solutions to differential equations. For example, let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}, (f(x))^2$ is differentiable and the derivative of $(f(x))^2)$is $f(x)$ i.e. $((f(x))^2)'=f(x)$. 
If we assume $f$ is differentiable we get that $2f(x)f'(x)=f(x) \implies f(x)(2f'(x)-1)=0 \implies f(x)=0$ or $f'(x)=\frac{1}{2} \implies f(x)=\frac{x}{2} + c, c \in \mathbb{R}$.
But $f(x)$ is not necesarily differentiable, therefore the following functions also satisfy the requirments stated above: 
[image]
along with $f(x)=0$

For this specific example I have found a proof, but I am wondering if there is a way to generalize theese types of equations. 
For instance: Let $f, g, h : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a functions such that $g(f(x))$ is differentiable. Find all functions f that satisfy the equation $g(f(x))'=h(f(x))$.

Or maybe generalize it further: Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ a function and $g, h : \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$, such that $\frac{dg(f(x), x)}{dx}$ exists. Find all functions $f$ that satisfy $\frac{dg(f(x), x)}{dx}=h(f(x), x)$. 
Is there a general way to solve theese equations?